# Solana - Commitment vs preflightCommitment

Tags: solana

I'm curious what the difference between `preflightCommitment` and `commitment` is.

Also, what are the different types of commitments listed below.

```
export type Commitment =
    | 'processed'
    | 'confirmed'
    | 'finalized'
    | 'recent'
    | 'single'
    | 'singleGossip'
    | 'root'
    | 'max';
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`preflightCommitment` is the commitment used for the preflight transaction, AKA the transaction simulation, whereas `commitment` is used for the actual transaction.

As for the different commitments, they're all listed at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment

Some of those terms are old, but here's roughly how they would translate:

- `processed` = `recent`
- `confirmed` = `singleGossip` = `single`
- `finalized` = `root` = `max`

Comment: Thanks! why does simulations require some kind of commitment here?

Also, does that mean `recent, singleGossip, single, root, max` are all deprecated?

Comment: Per the definition of commitment: "For preflight checks and transaction processing, Solana nodes choose which bank state to query" so if you choose "finalized" it means that you're running your transaction against a finalized block, and if you choose "processed", you're running your transaction against the most recent block.

And yes, those are all now deprecated.